# bxSlider using numbered pager

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

I have this slider which works fine. I need to change the pager to be numbered like on the second image.
[image: slider with normal pager]

rendered by the following code

```
$('#dinner-slider').bxSlider({
    pager: true,
    auto: true,
    minSlides: 3,
    maxSlides: 3,
    slideWidth: 500,
    slideMargin: 10,
    control: false
});
```

The html looks like this (I am using [holder.js](https://github.com/imsky/holder) for placeholder images)

```
<ul id="dinner-slider">
    <li><img src="holder.js/100px200?auto=yes&textmode=exact&random=yes&outline=yes" /></li>
    <li><img src="holder.js/100px200?auto=yes&textmode=exact&random=yes&outline=yes" /></li>
    <li><img src="holder.js/100px200?auto=yes&textmode=exact&random=yes&outline=yes" /></li>
    <li><img src="holder.js/100px200?auto=yes&textmode=exact&random=yes&outline=yes" /></li>
    <li><img src="holder.js/100px200?auto=yes&textmode=exact&random=yes&outline=yes" /></li>
    <li><img src="holder.js/100px200?auto=yes&textmode=exact&random=yes&outline=yes" /></li>
</ul>
```

I want it appear like this
[image: slider with desired pager]

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer:
http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-1
http://bxslider.com/examples/custom-next-prev-selectors

```
<div id="bx-pager">
  <a href="" id="slider-prev"> << </a>
  <a data-slide-index="0" href="">1</a>
  <a data-slide-index="1" href="">2</a>
  <a data-slide-index="2" href="">3</a>
  <a  href="" id="slider-next"> >> </a>
</div>

$('#dinner-slider').bxSlider({

 // add to your code
  nextSelector: '#slider-next',
  prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
  nextText: 'Onward →',
  prevText: '← Go back'
});
```

Comment: But the slides number is unknown. They are dynamically generated.

Comment: The number you can put dynamically by loop

Comment: I don't know how to do that but I think I can handle that in the source